# Making built-in classes for using it in HTML is good idea or not matter?

Tags: html, css

Have I to make class for each style to reusable them within HTML to increase the performance?
Or grouping style is a good alternative?

Comment: Of course Yes! It is always a better option to use reusable components. It not only increases performance but helps you to maintain the code properly.
As a good programmer, you should always use the DRY(don't repeat yourself) principle.